# What is the fastest way to transfer data from Hadoop DFS to a local filesystem?

Tags: hadoop

I always use "dfs -get" or "dfs -cat", but I imagine there might be something better. With "dfs -cat | pv", it appears my network connection isn't saturating (I'm getting only 20MB/sec).  Is there a way to parallelize it, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dfs -cat` has to shuttle all the data through that single process, with poor parallelism.

What I've done is run a mapper-only streaming job that dumps to scratch space on each disk and then rsync back to a single machine. Both parts do a good job of exercising the cluster to its full; and since rsync is nicely idempotent you can start it going at the same time as the hdfs->local part.